# Batch script save to file command without quotes

Tags: batch-file

I need to save 2 python commands without quotes so but I dont know how to skip quotes in a saved command.

```
SET PYTHON_COMMANDS="command.py"
IF EXIST %PYTHON_COMMANDS% DEL /F %PYTHON_COMMANDS%
(
    echo "connect("weblogic", "xxx", "t3s://x.x.x.x:7002")"

) >%PYTHON_COMMANDS%
```

file output:

```
"connect("weblogic", "xxx", "t3s://x.x.x.x:7002")"
```

but I wish to have in the file only the command

```
connect("weblogic", "xxx", "t3s://x.x.x.x:7002")
```

Comment: If you don't want the quotes - why do you `echo` them? (you'l get another issue when you remove them; escape the closing `)` to prevent the code block to end early: `echo connect("weblogic", "xxx", "t3s://x.x.x.x:7002"^)`). You don't need to delete the file, as `>` will overwrite it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it, you'll have to escape every special character.

Batch files have their own, strange quoting rules, but fortunately, your string doesn't have too many characters that need escaping:

- `)` should be `^)` if this line in a code block (i.e. a block of code surrounded by parentheses), it will work without it as well otherwise
- `(` can be escaped, but doesn't really need and have to be
- Other characters don't have to be escaped.

So, the following should work:

```
 connect("weblogic", "xxx", "t3s://x.x.x.x:7002"^)
```

But don't forget that when you change command (the address, for example), you'll have to recheck for special characters (such as `% -> %%` and `& -> ^&` that occur frequently in URLs)!